# Pytorch: Numpy Arrays

Tags: numpy, pytorch

Can I use numpy arrays when using pytorch?

I am converting a code from tensorflow to pytorch and the code uses numpy arrays during the computation. Can I keep my inputs as numpy arrays during the computation or do I have to convert them to torch tensors?

Answer (score 0):

If that array is being passed to a Pytorch model with pytorch `nn` layers, then it **MUST** be a <torch.tensor> and **NOT** a numpy array.

Depending on the Pytorch layer, the tensor has to be in a specific shape like for nn.Conv2d layers you must have a 4d torch tensor and for nn.Linear you must have a 2d torch tensor.

This is among many reasons, it cannot be a numpy array.

Sarthak